# How can I safely allow a user to define the name of a new column in SQL?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm building a very basic inventory management application using Xamarin Forms to construct the UI and MySQL to build and maintain the database. I'd like the user to be able to define their own properties for each item to allow flexibility in what the application can tell the user about inventory. My plan was to have things that all items of one type share (ex. all cameras with model number 0000 are 5mp cameras) be inserted into the the table of all items as a new column that will just be NULL for items that don't have that particular attribute (ex. refrigerators don't have a resolution).

The following is how I would accomplish the task if I cared nothing for the threat of SQL injection.

```
    //this Dictionary would be populated by data pulled from user inputs.        
    IDictionary<string, object> userProps = new Dictionary<string, object>;

    MySQLCommand dBCommand = new MySQLCommand();

    foreach(string prop in userProps.Keys)
    {
       dbCommand.CommandText = dbCommand.CommandText + "ALTER TABLE items ADD COLUMN " + prop + " " + userProps[prop].GetType().ToString() + ";";  
    }
```

Then of course open a connection and execute the statement. I know I can replace userProps[prop].GetType().ToString() with an instance of the SQLParameter class but it does not appear to have a datatype suitable to a column or table name (which becomes important for properties with variable values like MAC addresses). I'm hoping I'm a fool and there is a simple way to accomplish this without exposing the application to SQL injection. If not I am open to suggestions for a more intensive solution. Much gratitude to anyone who takes the time to read this and render assistance.

Comment: A common approach is to have a table of `Properties` (`PropertyId`, `Property`) and allow users to define new properties. A table like `ItemProperties` ( `ItemId`, `PropertyId`, `PropertyValue` ) allows the user to associate properties with items. SQL injection is not an issue. Useful queries may become rather a nuisance, e.g. finding all _shoes_ with  properties _color_ = _red_ and _size_ = _8.5_. It also gets increasingly problematic when the properties have different types, ranges and other attributes. OTOH, it avoids a sea of columns that aren't applicable to most rows.

Comment: User must have the DDL privileges never.

Comment: @HABO That's going to make queries a bit tedious but I suppose if that's the only safe way to do it it's the way it has to be. I wasn't to worried about the largely null values because I don't anticipate the scale of the program reaching a point where that becomes to problematic, at least not for a good long while. My other idea was to just check the string designated for the name of the property for problem characters like ';', '=', or '-' at the point the user enters the data but I don't know how bulletproof that is.

Comment: In SQL Server [`QuoteName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) provides a way to handle nuisance names, e.g. having whitespace or unusual characters. I don't know if there is a mysql equivalent. Allowing users to add properties is a source of never ending challenges. What data types do you allow? How do you implement constraints? (`SellBy` must be a date in the future, but not more than 2 weeks.) Faux duplicates? (`Width` for a shoe isn't the same as for wallpaper.) Lists of valid values, e.g. T-shirt sizes?

Comment: You might want to take a look at key value databases, or other non-sql databases that may be more suitable for use cases like this.

Comment: @HABO QuoteName does not exist in MySQL but from some brief research it appears the function can be written without to much effort as shown here [link](https://www.dbload.com/articles/QUOTENAME%20function%20in%20MSSQL%20and%20MySQL.htm). Using a similarly constructed function I could prevent the use of ';' inside of a column or table name as defined by the user but would that be enough to prevent injection? The user input would always follow CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE so it seems logical. (Apologies for my backtick key being busted)

Comment: Short answer: I don't know, I'm a SQL Server flunky. Attempting to clean up user supplied object names is always fraught with opportunity, usually for the opposition. It must be done perfectly everywhere to succeed. Not just the `alter table` but _every_ reference to the column. Backticks do seem to break executable [comments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comments.html), e.g. `select /*!version()*/`. What else is lurking?

Comment: @HABO Fair enough. I'm going to move forward under the assumption that it will work in this instance as the data stored here isn't really all that sensitive and the people with access to the this particular functionality will be limited. I would think that preventing special characters in the name of the column at it's creation would prevent those same characters from appearing in references to the column. Perhaps I'll learn a hard lesson, time will tell. One thing is certain, I'll be paying special attention to this particular functionality moving forward. Thanks for your help!